# Ruby splat and << operators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bit-shift, splat

I want to do this:

```
a << *b
```

but this happens in irb:

```
1.9.3p327 :020 > a
 => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
1.9.3p327 :021 > b
 => [5, 6, 7] 
1.9.3p327 :022 > a << *b
SyntaxError: (irb):22: syntax error, unexpected tSTAR
a << *b
      ^
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Wouldn't `a + b` be more intuitive for this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look the reason here :

```
 a = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
 b = [5, 6, 7] 
 p a.<<(*b)
 # ~> -:3:in `<<': wrong number of arguments (3 for 1) (ArgumentError)
 # ~>  from -:3:in `<main>'
```

`<<` method expects only one argument.So now as below splat(`*`) is an operator,which will create `5,6,7` ,which `<<` method do not expect,rather it expects only one object. Thus design of Ruby don't allowing `*` before `b`.

```
 a = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
 b = [5, 6, 7] 
 p a << *
 # ~> -:3: syntax error, unexpected *

 a = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
 b = [5, 6, 7] 
 p a << *b
 # ~> -:3: syntax error, unexpected *
 # ~> p a << *b
 # ~>         ^
```

That is why the 2 legitimate errors :

- wrong number of arguments (3 for 1) (ArgumentError)
- syntax error, unexpected *

Probably you can use -

```
 a = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
 b = [5, 6, 7] 
 p a.push(*b)
 # >> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 5):

This line will do your job:

```
a += b
```

Comment: I like this answer as opposed to those trying to explain how to use the `*` character for this reason: think of how other people are going to respond when looking at this code. Are you making it obvious what you're doing, or misdirecting them? An important thing to remember about Ruby is that even though it does have some awesome shortcuts, simplicity is the single greatest characteristic about great code.

Comment: I agree.  But I also need to understand why thing work and why they don't.

Comment: ...which means a = a + b for anyone not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 a.concat(b)
```

it will output:

```
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7]
```

The solution you want is

```
a.concat b
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

However, you might find this a little interesting

```
b.each &a.method(:<<)
a
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

This says "call method `a#<<` on each element in b"

Equivalent to

```
b.each &a.method(:push)
a
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the type signature: ary << obj → ary. It expects exactly one parameter. Try: a.push(*b) (push(obj, ... ) → ary)